# Trying to print a CANVAS of HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, printing

I'm trying to print the content from a tag of HTML `div`, until here, everything is ok, so, I'm making with the library `fabricJS` that a user can write text or can add an image in my page.

But, when I'm trying to print that content in my page, the tag `div` from the hello world (hola mundo in spanish) until the section of `canvas`, I'm getting a mistake because the preview of print from my navigator its in white and its doesn't works with the content of canvas.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card mb-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
      <div class="container" id="print-section">
        ¡Hola Mundo!
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400px" height="100px" style="border:solid;">
          Hola Mundo!
        </canvas>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="print('printSectionId')">Print</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="inciarCanvas()">Start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT/ANGULAR**

```
canvas: any;
  constructor() { }
  print(): void {
    let printContents,
        popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
          </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', );
    this.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('¡Just write!'));
    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f47d.png', (image) => {
      image.set({
        left: 50,
        top: 70,
      });

      this.canvas.add(image);
    });
  }
```

> **Note:** If I press the key `ctrl` + `p` it shows all the content from my page, including the canvas and all de content (Text and Martian image) and I coudn't add a image for being more clear in my need (for reputation).

What can I do for find a solution for my problem or what I'm doing wrong?

¡Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar task in Angular4 application, so I am sharing that logic here.
I have used HTML 5 Canvas with kinetic-JS. Kinetic-JS is used to draw images, lines or any shape on Canvas. The requirement was to create some CK-editor or HTML editor type of control.
When I successfully drawn all the shapes, the next challenging thing for me was to print the content of canvas, not the whole page.
I was having a json of all the shapes that I draw on canvas using Kinetic-JS. So I used that same Json to redraw those shapes on a "Print"button click to create a SVG.(You can use the objects of inmemory shapes that was already drawn).
I used that SVG for printing by sending that SVG to Printer.

If you need more further help than I'll feel more happy to do so.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understad, but, how can I do a SVG and print it?

Comment: It depends upon your existing implementation that how you want to generate a SVG.
You can directly generate SVG from CANVAS or you can create HTML and convert it into SVG.